# sort array after descriptor

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, sorting

This is some of my code. 
And everything works fine. But not the sorting. I want to sort my Array after "Altitude"
But it doesn't work so here is my code and i hope that somebody can help me.

```
        //Berechnung der Entfernung
        erdradius = 6371;

        //Koordinaten von Datenbank in String schreiben
        NSString *latitude = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
        NSString *longitude = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Longitude"];

        entfernung = 0;
        double lat1 = eigLat;                   //eigener Standort Latitude
        double long1 = eigLon;                  //eigener Standort Longitude
        double lat2 = [latitude doubleValue];   //Standort Heurigen Latitude
        double long2 = [longitude doubleValue]; //Standort Heurigen Longitude

        //Da man mit Bogenmaß rechnen muss!
        double lat1rechnen = lat1*2*M_PI/360;
        double long1rechnen = long1*2*M_PI/360;
        double lat2rechnen = lat2*2*M_PI/360;
        double long2rechnen = long2*2*M_PI/360;

        //Formel zur Berechnung
        entfernung = (erdradius * (2 * asin(sqrt(((sin(((lat1rechnen-lat2rechnen)/2)*(lat1rechnen-lat2rechnen)/2))+cos(lat1rechnen)*cos(lat2rechnen)*(sin(((long1rechnen-long2rechnen)/2)*(long1rechnen-long2rechnen)/2)))))));

        //Werte in Strings damit man sie ausgeben kann
        weg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km", entfernung];
        HeurigenName = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];


        newsMutable = [news mutableCopy];

        for (NSMutableDictionary* entry in newsMutable)
        {
            [entry setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:weg] //[NSNumber numberWithDouble:entfernung]
                     forKey:@"Altitude"];
        }


    NSLog(@"%@",newsMutable);

        news = [newsMutable copy];

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Altitude" ascending:YES];
    [news sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]];
    wegsorted = [news copy];


    //Ausgabe
    cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text =[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Altitude"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Altitude"];

    return cell;
```

Can somebody help me how i can fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` *returns a new sorted array*, it does not sort the array itself.
You can either use

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [news sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:...];
```

to get a new sorted array, or use `sortUsingDescriptors`:

```
[news sortUsingDescriptors:...]
```

to sort the (mutable) array `news` itself.

Another problem is that in your for-loop you set the same "Altitude" value for all objects in the array, therefore sorting by that key does not change anything.

Note that `newsMutable = [news mutableCopy]` creates a new array, but does not copy the elements in the array, so that the following for-loop modifies the items from the `news` array.

Comment: But every object in the array have another Altutude when i give it out in my TableView. But in want to sort it after this Altitude.

Comment: @theandrew: I have difficulties understanding your code (even if I understand German :-). It seems that this code is called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, is that correct? - Sorting the table view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` cannot work. You should sort the array only once before the table view is displayed, e.g. in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @theandrew: Why do you call it "Altitude"? It seems to be a *distance*. And you should put NSNumber values into the objects, not strings, to make the sorting work.

Comment: because it is easier. i have Altitude in my array and don't ned is so i save it in atitude. Do you think this is a bad way?

Comment: @theandrew: Note also that the CoreLocation framework has a method `distanceFromLocation` which you could use.